# ASP.NET event order during postback or initial request

Tags: asp.net, postback, page-lifecycle

Could I get some confirmations from the community that I'm not going mad, and that the life cycle of a page during post back is in deed in a different order to when the page is initally requested.

If this is the case pointers towards references/articles outlining the order would be greatly appreciated.

(A postback equivalent of [the page life cycle image](http://www.robincurry.org/blog/content/binary/o_aspNet_Page_LifeCycle.jpg) would be great)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour is slightly different but the order is the same. In this respect "Postback" is essentially a state flag on the request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

(nice image btw)

edit: thinking about it, perhaps it would be helpful to outline your problem? Mentioning postback makes me think it's about databinding perhaps? The article should be helpful though.

Comment: Thanks, it's pride of place on our wall at work. Comes in handy when .NET does something you didn't expect!

Comment: The article is actually very helpful!
Regarding the problem it's actually very involved so i'll post it if I don't get much feed back.