# How Postback is detected on serverside of a webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wonder how postback is detected on serverside?
Generally, the state of controls on a page are stored in Viewstate and they traverse back and forth on every postback to the server.
Since http is stateless, how will the server differentiate between a `postback`ed page and Initial Page load.

we can use Page.IsPostback property which is auto set to true or false for postback and initial load respectively. But my question is what controls this assignment of true and false to Page.Ispostback property and how server figure out a form postback?
Is there any hidden field that server uses to detect a postback of a Page?

Comment: First page load is a HTTP GET request, after that they are POST requests.

Comment: So, if its a POST request for a form, is it safe to assume that its a postback?

Comment: I would say so, yes (most times). I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of ASP.NET, first page load is a HTTP GET request, after that they are POST requests.

[Similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352222/asp-net-event-order-during-postback-or-initial-request)

Technically, first page could be made as a POST, but this is not typical.

Comment: So, Server is book keeping pages for which it received POST after GET and marking them as postbacks. where is this information stored?

Comment: Yes, apparently a flag is set.

Comment: is the flag Page.Ispostback or  a flag on server memory which it assigns to Page.Ispostback property?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. If this is a critical app, I would take the time to study the MS documentation thoroughly. I would presume it's in server memory...

Comment: @IrishChieftaun: I found something that helps us understand. `http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/how-postback-works-in-asp-net/` and `http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=895&pId=-1` . just  like we expected, client sends some hiddenfields to server to detect the postback and based on this the IsPostback is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat complicated. `System.Web.UI.Page` weighs in at roughly 6500 lines with numerous public/internal dependencies.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Page.cs

From your earlier comment:

> just like we expected, client sends some hiddenfields to server to
>   detect the postback and based on this the IsPostback is set to true.

You are correct that hidden fields are used. IrishChieftain was also correct in pointing out that the HTTP verb is used in the determination.

The overall process is stateless.

`Page` proceeds through a number of steps to make the determination.

[Starting with ProcessRequestMain()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Page.cs,4622):

- Check if the page uses a `PageAdapter`.
- Call the `PageAdapter's` `DeterminePostBackMode()` method, or call `DeterminePostBackMode()` on the page itself.
- ...which calls `GetCollectionBasedOnMethod()`
- Is the request a POST? try to return the `Request.Form` collection.
- Do we get a collection from `GetCollectionBasedOnMethod()`? if so check for certain hidden fields.
- Check for a cross-page postback, and set `_pageFlags[isCrossPagePostRequest]` accordingly.

Those appear to be the prerequisites necessary to call `IsPostBack`.

```
public bool IsPostBack {
    get {
        if (_requestValueCollection == null)
            return false;

        // Treat it as postback if the page is created thru cross page postback.
        if (_isCrossPagePostBack)
            return true;

        // Don't treat it as a postback if the page is posted from cross page
        if (_pageFlags[isCrossPagePostRequest])
            return false;

        // Don't treat it as a postback if a view state MAC check failed and we
        // simply ate the exception.
        if (ViewStateMacValidationErrorWasSuppressed)
            return false;

        // If we're in a Transfer/Execute, never treat as postback (ASURT 121000)
        // Unless we are being transfered back to the original page, in which case
        // it is ok to treat it as a postback (VSWhidbey 117747)
        // Note that Context.Handler could be null (VSWhidbey 159775)
        if (Context.ServerExecuteDepth > 0 &&
            (Context.Handler == null || GetType() != Context.Handler.GetType())) {
            return false;
        }

        // If the page control layout has changed, pretend that we are in
        // a non-postback situation.
        return !_fPageLayoutChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.UI.Page class uses various methods to check whether the current request is a post back (setting the IsPostBack property). Some (not all) of these are:

1. Check whether the current request is a cross page post back, ie, whether it is a post request to the current page from another page. If so the request is treated as a post back.
2. There is a __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR hidden field in every HTML page rendered by .Net. If in a request received by the page, this hidden field is absent, or there was some error in the validation of the field's content then the request is not treated as a Post back.
3. If the request to the page is via a Server.Transfer, then it is not treated as a post back. There is an exception to this case, if the Server.Transfer to this page was initiated from this page itself then request is treated as a post back.
4. If the layout of the current page has changed since the last response, Page class will pretend that the request is a non-post back request. The layout changes are identified using the view state information received from the request. There are 2 view state related, .NET hidden fields in every response which assist in determining layout changes.

   - __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
   - __VIEWSTATE

More information can be obtained from the [source code for System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Page.cs,1655) property

The Visual Studio solution for this source code is also available for [download](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html)